# SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE @0 AND OR?

Tags: sql

I have this simple query

```
db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 LIKE @0 AND OR value2 LIKE @0", filter);
```

I can use either the

```
AND
```

statement or the

```
OR
```

statement. Is there a way to say that I want everythin from a table where value1 like @0 AND OR value2 @0?? how can I use an AND OR?

Comment: if you want records if any of the one condition is true then use ``OR`` if you want both conditions shoulde be satisified the use ``AND``

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What results you'd expect?

Comment: What do you think "and or" means? Because I suspect it is what most computer and math folk mean by "or" by itself. Contrast "xor".

Comment: What is `AND OR`?  That is not only not a SQL operator but I don't recognize it from other languages either.  It would be helpful it you edited your question, adding sample data with desired results.

Comment: If I want to search for the complete naem of a person, I need that input that wa written to fit either the name AND OR the surname. it is not the same to search a person based on its surname, name or both name and surname at once

Comment: Again : what do you mean by "and or" in the above sentence? Because I suspect, as already stated, that in logic terms this is "or".

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a very accurate answer very quickly just as soon as you explain what you want in a way that anyone else can understand

Comment: Sory for the misunderstood question, I could solve my problem, but I had a worng interpretention about my problem itself, so sory about this question

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use both simultaneously this way.

If you want to get records if any one of condition is true then use `OR`:

```
db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 LIKE @0 OR value2 LIKE @0", filter)
```

If you want both condition should be true to fetch results then use `AND`:

```
 db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 LIKE @0 AND value2 LIKE @0", filter)
```

But this is wrong by syntax:

```
db.Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value1 LIKE @0 AND OR value2 LIKE @0", filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly just want `OR` here. In logic terms, `OR` allows for one or both conditions to be satisfied.